# PHP log full of suhosin errors

Tags: php, html, linux, logging

Hello I have simple php script well it is more a html file with few php lines.
Yet it produces tons of errors in log that look like this on every line:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I can not locate in nowhere in code where suhosin might been called...

This error is present on 2 different servers.

**EDIT:**
In phpinfo there is no suhosin present...

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to delete this or it will end up being closed as not being helpful to others. Suhosin is a dead project, it's been removed from most modern OS repositories since it is no longer maintained.

Comment: suhosin is most likely trying to be loaded from one of the config files. Start in php.ini and comment out or remove any lines trying to load it if you just want to get rid of it. You may also have additional ini files being parsed, which should show up in your phpinfo as "Additional .ini files parsed"

Answer (score 0):

We will likely need more information in order to provide an accurate resolution, such as What version of PHP is installed on your system? however I will give you a general resolution.

Generally this issue is caused by PHP Upgrade, most recent PHP versions does not support suhosin as this only applied to older versions of php that needed additional security.

If you are on a shared hosting server you need to contact to your hosting provider and notify them about this issue, they are likely able to resolve it quickly.

If you are on a Dedicated server, VPS server or a localhost environment you can solve this issue by following the steps below:

1. Find your php.ini location [You can use `phpinfo()` to locate php.ini file]
2. Open the php.ini file and search `suhosin.so`
3. When you find suhosin comment this line `extension = "suhosin.so"` by adding semicolon at the beginning of the line, For example: `;extension = "suhosin.so"`
4. Save this file
5. Restart Apache `service httpd restart`

Note: If ClouldLinux installed on your server,  you need to force update CageFS by issuing the following command at the command line `cagefsctl --force-update`